Custom implementation of an implicit function in vtk
In vtk, I can create an implicit function representing a sphere like so:
my_function = vtk.vtkSphere()

sample = vtk.vtkSampleFunction()

sample.SetImplicitFunction(my_function)
# ... rest of the code

This works fine. But I am trying my own implementation of an implicit function
class vtkMySphere(vtk.vtkImplicitFunction):
    def __init__(self, center=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], radius=1.0):
        super(vtkMySphere, self).__init__()
        self.Center = center
        self.Radius = radius

    def EvaluateFunction(self, x):
        dx = x[0] - self.Center[0]
        dy = x[1] - self.Center[1]
        dz = x[2] - self.Center[2]
        return dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz - self.Radius * self.Radius

    def EvaluateGradient(self, x):
        grad = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        grad[0] = 2 * (x[0] - self.Center[0])
        grad[1] = 2 * (x[1] - self.Center[1])
        grad[2] = 2 * (x[2] - self.Center[2])
        return grad

my_function = vtk.vtkMySphere()
sample.SetImplicitFunction(my_function)

This throws an error:
my_function = vtkMySphere(center=[0, 0, 0], radius=0.125)
TypeError: this is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated

How should I proceed constructing my own implementation?
I am using vtk version 9.2.6 and python version 3.10.10
